# Can't start JXBrowser

Tags: jxbrowser, libcrypto

I reinstalled my OS due to some problem, I copied my old project and now I can't get JXBrowser works correctly.  I've got a licence for Open Source project. The log says this

```
04:49:31 INFO: OS name: Linux
04:49:31 INFO: JRE version: 1.8.0_91 64-bit
04:49:31 INFO: JxBrowser version: 6.4
04:49:31 INFO: JxBrowser type: HEAVYWEIGHT
04:49:31 INFO: Starting IPC...
04:49:31 INFO: Starting IPC Server...
04:49:31 INFO: Starting socket server
04:49:31 INFO: Starting socket server at port 1101...
04:49:31 INFO: Starting IPC Process...
04:49:31 INFO: Starting Chromium process...
04:49:31 INFO: The '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0' library exists: FALSE
04:49:31 INFO: The '/tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-49.0.2623.110.6.4/libudev.so.0' library exists: TRUE
04:49:31 INFO: The '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11' library exists: FALSE
04:49:31 INFO: The '/tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-49.0.2623.110.6.4/libgcrypt.so.11' library exists: TRUE
04:49:31 INFO: The '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0' library exists: FALSE
04:49:31 INFO: The '/tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-49.0.2623.110.6.4/libcrypto.so.1.0.0' library exists: FALSE
04:49:31 INFO: Looking for libcrypto.so.x.x.x in '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/'...
04:49:31 INFO: Looking for libcrypto.so.x.x.x in '/lib64/'...
04:49:31 INFO: Looking for libcrypto.so.x.x.x in '/usr/lib64/'...
04:49:31 INFO: Failed to find libcrypto.so.x.x.x
04:49:31 INFO: Command line: /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-49.0.2623.110.6.4/jxbrowser-chromium 1101 2837 --disable-surfaces 
04:49:31 INFO: Chromium process exit code 127
04:49:31 INFO: /tmp/jxbrowser-chromium-49.0.2623.110.6.4/jxbrowser-chromium: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.IPCException: IPC process exited. Exit code: 127
    at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.d.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
04:49:32 INFO: Stopping Server...
04:49:32 INFO: Stopping Server... [DONE]
04:49:32 INFO: Waiting process exit...
```

I'm running it on Kali 2.0 and Eclipse Mars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that Chromium engine failed to find the `libcrypto.so.1.0.0` system library. Please try installing this library and check if it helps.

Comment: I checked on my computer and I found that I've got usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.2 because I've got the latest version of OpenSSL. Do I have to downgrade to 1.0.0?

Comment: Looking at JXBrowser's log I think that it looks for it in lib folder but I've got in usr/lib

Comment: @Leonardo where is this log?